# How to organize MySQL table for multi player game Win/Loss reports

Tags: python, mysql

I used Python to parse plain text game reports from a game server, now I want to store the WIN/LOSS info in MySQL but I've been reading for hours and cant figure out a good way.

The plain text reports look like this:

```
name="9" id=#000094
clienttag=W2BN type="melee" option="normal"
created="Tue Jul 21 23:22:26 MSK" started="Tue Jul 21 23:23:02 MSK" ended="Tue Jul 21 23:24:32 MSK"
mapfile="Garden of War.pud" mapauth="Blizzard" mapsize=256x256 tileset="Unknown"
joins=3 maxplayers=8


sh4de            DRAW    
D.StyLez         DRAW    
Player           DRAW    


On map "Garden of War.pud":


sh4de was Orc and played for 1 minute

  Overall Score 1
             1 for Units
             0 for Structures
             0 for Resources

  Units Score 1
             1 Units Produced
             0 Units Killed
             0 Units Lost

  Structures Score 0
             0 Structures Constructed
             0 Structures Razed
             0 Structures Lost

  Resources Score 0
             0 Gold Mined
             0 Lumber Harvested
             0 Oil Harvested
             0 Total Spent
,
On map "Garden of War.pud":

D.StyLez was Orc and played for 1 minute

  Overall Score 2
             1 for Units
             1 for Structures
             0 for Resources

  Units Score 1
             1 Units Produced
             0 Units Killed
             0 Units Lost

  Structures Score 1
             1 Structures Constructed
             0 Structures Razed
             0 Structures Lost

  Resources Score 0
             0 Gold Mined
             0 Lumber Harvested
             0 Oil Harvested
             0 Total Spent
,
On map "Garden of War.pud":

Player was Human and played for 1 minute

  Overall Score 1
             1 for Units
             0 for Structures
             0 for Resources

  Units Score 1
             1 Units Produced
             0 Units Killed
             0 Units Lost

  Structures Score 0
             0 Structures Constructed
             0 Structures Razed
             0 Structures Lost

  Resources Score 0
             0 Gold Mined
             0 Lumber Harvested
             0 Oil Harvested
             0 Total Spent
,
```

I've already parsed the whole thing, I have variables for who won, who lost, what points each person got in which categories, and all the game information at the top of the report.

### But NO IDEA how to put this in MySQL

the goal is to be able to do detailed queries like

"Select all games where sh4de was orc and beat d.sytelz"

Its an 8 player game. The only thing I could come up with was to be able to query who won or lost a game I could do:

"Select * from game_reports where winner_1 or winner_2 or winner_3 or winner_4 or winner_5 or ........ = sh4de and loser_1 or loser_2 or loser_3 ... = D.stylez"

but I wont be able to know which "winner_#" sh4de was, so I wont be able to find out if he was orc or human...

Also if I did things this way (winner_1, winner_2 winner_3) each row would be massive - winner 1 has to have winner_1_overall_score, winner_1_unit_score etc x8 winners, x8 losers, x8 DRAW, x8 Disc

There has to be a "right" way to do this, I am so stumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this is actually really difficult for anyone to answer because we have very little context for what exactly it is you're doing.  I'm going to assume that you have basic knowledge of MySQL, so I'll do a rough outline here.  I'm just going to sketch the tables out roughly and hopefully that will give you a starting point.

---

Format:

```
Table
-Column [Type] [Relation] [Notes]
```

You'll first probably need a player table to keep track of all your players.  You can skip this if you don't care about tracking players between games.

```
Player
-ID Int PK AutoIncrement
-Name Varchar(50)
-(Whatever other metadata you want to store about the player)
```

Next you'll need a table to track each game:

```
Game
-ID Int PK AutoIncrement
-Map Varchar(255)
-Time DateTime
```

Now you need to do a many to many relationship between the games and the player.  I'm going to include the score in this table to save space, but you might want to split that out.

```
GamePlayerScore
-GameID FK(Game::ID) PK
-PlayerID FK(Player::ID) PK
-Score Int
-Class varchar(50)
```

---

Obviously this is an extremely example and you're going to want to split things up much more, but you should get the basic idea.  I wouldn't suggest storing the winner of each game, and rather determining it in the code by pulling the score.  Since you also have different score types, you'll probably want a table to hold each score with a 'type' column.

Once you have your tables set up you can use joins to aggregate your data properly and do the sort of queries you're talking about.

---

EDIT: Archer asked about how to handle cases where a player had a higher score, but still lost.  Without knowing how wins are determined I would suggest modifying my previous answer to something like this:

```
GamePlayerScore
-ID PK AutoIncrement
-PlayerID FK(Player::ID)
-GameID FK(Game::ID)
-Place Int *Number representing how well the player placed*
-PlayerClass

Score
-ID PK AutoIncrement
-GamePlayerScoreID FK(GamePlayerScore::ID)
-Type varchar(50) *Overall, units, structures, etc.*
-Value Int

ScoreStat
-ScoreID FK(Score::ID) PK
-Name varchar(50) *gold mined, lumber harvested, etc.*
-Value Int
```

This was super quick and it can probably do better, but you can see how things get more specific as you drill down the tables.  In addition, you don't have a separate table for each thing, but rather separate everything into similar categories and use types to sort everything out.

Also, since you're new to joins, I would recommend [this](https://bigsnarf.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/sqljoins.jpg) image when writing them to help you figure out what data you're actually selecting.  Would be happy to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks! This will be my first relational database, its pretty much blowing my mind right now. I may run into the problem of someone getting a higher score, but still losing (say they harvested a ton of gold, but they didnt build enought soldiers and so they were still defeated by a lower scoring opponent). Any idea for tracking winners/losers/discers/draws? --- I think I can just store it in GamePlayerScore --- can u write me a quick SQL query example to join tables and find where 'sh4d3' beat 'player' and sh4d3 on map = 'war' for example

Comment: I'm not really sure how you're determining winners, so it's hard for me to answer.  I'll edit my answer with an idea for that.

Comment: The report tells me the winners, so i already know it.. in this example, it was a 3 way draw however so the report says "sh4de            DRAW    
D.StyLez         DRAW    
Player           DRAW " but sometimes it will say Player 1 WIN player2 LOSS player3 DRAW player4 DISC

Comment: Still trying to wrap my mind around how to craft a query that will be like "Select games where Player1 beat player2 and map='war' and player1='human' and player2='orc' ...............etc

Comment: So you're last question actually requires a sub query to pull the sort of data you're looking for.  Otherwise things are going to get very long and complex.  I don't really have enough space to go into it here, but I would recommend starting out with easier queries, and building up to that.  In the beginning, it's not the worst thing in the world if you have to do multiple queries to get the information that you need.